# Node.JS No DB selected even though it is

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

SO I am getting a "No database selected" error in my node.js code. However, it is selected, and the connection statement does return a successful message when I first launch it. My way of inserting follows this tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/)

I also installed the MySQL module for node using npm, though I suspect that even though it is under the module it is still not functioning correctly as even if I put a database to be something that doesn't exist it will still say a successful connection. So I guess two part question: how to make sure I actually downloaded the MySQL component correctly, and am I making any mistake in my bot? Code below.

```
// Dependencies =========================
var  
    twit = require('twit'),
    config = require('./config');

var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection(
{    
   host: "localhost",
   user: "root",
   password: "Jaljap2732!",
   dateStrings: true,
   datebase: "rawdata"
});



var Twitter = new twit(config);

con.connect(function(err) {
   if(err) {
       console.log("Sorry Fam, error connecting");
   } else {
       console.log("Connection Successful")
   }
});



var searchTweets = function(){  
  var params = {
      q: 'since:2017-04-01',  // REQUIRED
      result_type: 'recent',
      count:'10',
      lang: 'en'
  }
  // find the tweet
  Twitter.get('search/tweets', params, function(err,data){

    // find tweets
    var tweet = data.statuses;

      //console.log(tweet);
   for(var result in tweet) {
       console.log("text: " + tweet[result].text);
       var created_at = tweet[result].created_at;
       var date = created_at.split(" ");
       var month = date[1];

       var sqlDate = date[5] + "-" + monthToInt(month) + "-" + date[2]; 


       var data = {
         tweet:  tweet[result].text,
         posted: sqlDate,
         User_idUser:  tweet[result].user.screen_name 
       };

       con.query('INSERT INTO tweet SET ?', data, function(err, rows) {
          if(err) throw err;
           else {
               console.log("Data from DB");
               console.log(rows);
           }
       });

       console.log("Posted at: " + date[1] + " " + date[2] + " " + date[5]);
       console.log("Converted Date: " + monthToInt(month));
       console.log("User: " + tweet[result].user.screen_name);
   }

  });
}
// grab & 'favorite' as soon as program is running...
searchTweets();  
// 'favorite' a tweet in every 15 minutes
setInterval(searchTweets, 900000);


function monthToInt(month) {

    //We will return a string representation of the month
    //using numbers in order to insert it into our SQL table. 


    var result = "";

    switch(month) {
        case "Jan":
            console.log("Janaury: 01");
            result = "01";
            break;
        case "Feb":
            console.log("February: 02");
            result = "02";
            break;
        case "Mar":
            console.log("March: 03");
            result = "03";
            break;
        case "Apr":
            console.log("April: 04");
            result = "04";
            break;
        case "May":
            console.log("May: 05");
            result = "05";
            break;
        case "Jun":
            console.log("Jun: 06");
            result = "06";
            break;
        case "Jul":
            console.log("Jul: 07");
            result = "07";
            break;
        case "Aug":
            console.log("August: 08");
            result = "08";
            break;
        case "Sept":
            console.log("September: 09");
            result = "09";
            break;
        case "Sep":
            console.log("September: 09");
            result = "09";
            break;
        case "Oct":
            console.log("October: 10");
            result = "10";
            break;
        case "Nov":
            console.log("November: 11");
            result = "11";
            break; 
        case "Dec":
            console.log("December: 12");
            result = "12";
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: dont you need to do all your tweeting inside the db connection callback?

Comment: Maybe? I am fairly new to node.js to be honest, and I am still getting the hang of call backs.

Comment: To make sure you downloaded it correctly you can go into the folder named `node_modules` delete the folder named `mysql` and then run `npm install mysql` this will re-install the package.

Comment: I am confident I did it correctly, I even tried to mess around with async. Still not happening

Comment: To make callbacks easier to handle, check out `async.series`, etc.: http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer here, but you have a race condition between the database connection and the Twitter reply.  You need to finish the connection first, then use it.  Right now, `Connection Successful` can happen after `INSERT INTO tweet SET ?`.

Comment: I see, once you have time can you explain how to solve this race condition?

Comment: yeah, so umm, I used the async series, and that still didn't give me anything. I tried to do doConnect first, then search tweets, it was just looping endlessly on connecting. Then I tried putting the search function in my connection success part, still says no DB

Answer (score 0):

It is a hack of a fix, but I just forced it to use the database in question using another query. I would seriously appreciate a solid answer, and not a vague comment answer describing a race condition as the way I see it the code executes sequentially. Nothing in the inside of the searchCode should ever execute before another thing.